# database schema one column entry references many rows from another table

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

Let's say we have a table called `Workorders` and another table called `Parts`. I would like to have a column in `Workorders` called `parts_required`. This column would contain a single item that tells me what parts were required for that workorder. Ideally, this would contain the quantities as well, but a second column could contain the quantity information if needed.

`Workorders` looks like

```
WorkorderID   date   parts_required
1             2/24      ?
2             2/25      ?
3             3/16      ?
4             4/20      ?
5             5/13      ?
6             5/14      ?
7             7/8       ?
```

`Parts` looks like

```
PartID    name           cost
1         engine         100
2         belt           5
3         big bolt       1
4         little bolt    0.5
5         quart oil      8 
6         Band-aid       0.1
```

---

***Idea 1***: create a string like `'1-1:2-3:4-5:5-4'`. My application would parse this string and show that I need --> 1 `engine`, 3 `belts`, 5 `little bolts`, and 4 `quarts of oil`.

**Pros** - simple enough to create and understand.

**Cons** - will make deep introspection into our data much more difficult. (costs over time, etc)

---

***Idea 2***: use a binary number. For example, to reference the above list (`engine`, `belt`, `little bolts`, `oil`) using an 8-bit integer would be 54, because 54 in binary representation is `110110`.

**Pros** - datatype is optimal concerning size. Also, I am guessing there are tricky math tricks I could use in my queries to search for parts used (don't know what those are, correct me if I'm in the clouds here).

**Cons** - I do not know how to handle quantity using this method. Also, Even with a 64-bit `BIGINT` still only gives me 64 parts that can be in my table. I expect many hundreds.

---

Any ideas? I am using `MySQL`. I may be able to use `PostgreSQL`, and I understand that they have more flexible `datatypes` like `JSON` and arrays, but I am not familiar with how querying those would perform. Also it would be much easier to stay with `MySQL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create a Relationship table?

You can create a table named Workorders_Parts with the following content:

|workorderId, partId|

So when you want to get all parts from a specific workorder you just type:

```
select p.name 
from parts p inner join workorders_parts wp on wp.partId = p.partId
where wp.workorderId = x;
```

what the query says is:

> Give me the name of parts that belongs to workorderId=x and are listed in table workorders_parts

Remembering that INNER JOIN means "INTERSECTION" in other words: data i'm looking for should exist (generally the id) in both tables

[image: inner join image]

IT will give you all part names that are used to build workorder x.

Lets say we have workorderId = 1 with partID = 1,2,3, it will be represented in our relationship table as:

workorderId | partId
1 | 1
1 | 2
1 | 3

Comment: What is the PK of Workorders_Parts? (maybe left out for brevity?) Also, would this handle quantities of the parts easily?

Comment: You dont need a PK for the workorders_parts since it is a relationship table. Primary key is used to separate tuples in meaning. in this case you have 3 tuples meaning the samething: "Parts of workorder" so there is no need to create a PK for it

Comment: Would it be ok to add a column in `Workorders_Parts` called `quantity`?

Comment: Yes totally ok.. Relationship tables accepts extra columns that only have meaning in the relation and not in the single part. In this case quantity only have sense in the relation "Workorder has 2 engines".. so you can create the column for it

Comment: Such JOIN Venn diagrams *seem* informative but only for illustrating the difference between inner and outer joins when you already understand what a join is. If you write a key for this one then you will find that so much must be understood just to interpret the diagram that it is not adding any value. Hint: What things are in each of the three zones? This diagram is closer to inner natural join of two tables with the same set of column names and corresponding types, or for values resulting from in the projections of the tables on id. (It's as unclear as 'INNER JOIN means "INTERSECTION"'.)